# JavaScript как просуммировать все значения массива за период дат

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Буду благодарен за помощь. Нужно просуммировать данные из массива за период дат, а конкретнее за месяц по ключу money. Сума должна быть общая за последний месяц. В одном случае должен быть общий подсчет всех данных из массива, а в втором где is_ftd true. Не знаю как правильно работать с такими условиями. Можно ли брать отсчет за последние 30 дней или нужно как-то работать с конкретним диапазоном.
Вот пример массива:

```html
var data = [
  {
      "id": 35,
      "money": 211.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 36,
      "money": 31.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
{
      "id": 37,
      "money": 89.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
{
      "id": 38,
      "money": 1274.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
{
      "id": 39,
      "money": 23.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": false
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно например так:

```js
var data = [
  {
      "id": 35,
      "money": 211.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
  {
      "id": 36,
      "money": 31.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
{
      "id": 37,
      "money": 89.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": true
  },
{
      "id": 38,
      "money": 1274.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
{
      "id": 39,
      "money": 23.0,
      "date": "2021-02-10",
      "is_ftd": false
  },
  {
      "id": 139,
      "money": 23.0,
      "date": "2021-01-31",
      "is_ftd": false
  }
];

const lastMonth = moment().month();

const res = data.reduce((acc, { date, money } ) => {
  return acc + (moment(date).month() === lastMonth ? money :0)
}, 0)

console.log(res);

//----------------------------------------------

const resIsFtdTrue = data.reduce((acc, { date, money, is_ftd } ) => {
  return acc + (moment(date).month() === lastMonth && is_ftd ? money :0)
}, 0)

console.log(resIsFtdTrue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```